# Image on image in mail

Tags: html, css, email

Is it possible in an email ( where it is recommended to use tables and inline css styles ) to put an image on top of another image? We want to put a stamp onto an image like this example :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the quantity of images, you may want to serve the image through an HTTP handler which dynamically adds the desired overlay. This allows you to avoid any email client HTML issues and having to manually edit (a potentially large and changing quantity) of images.

You can cache the results of the image processing operation to improve performance.

This method would start to shine if you have had dozens or hundreds of images, and/or you frequently changed the overlay contents. Otherwise, a static image will be easiest (record a Photoshop action and be done with it).

Example:

```
<!-- before -->
<img src="http://foo.com/static.jpg">

<!-- after -->
<img src="http://foo.com/handler?id=123&overlay=xyz">
```

Comment: We need indeed a lot of images with this kind of behavior and I will give it a try do create it automatically with imagemagick because the mails are generated automatically. Thanks for your input!

Comment: No problem. If you have any issues creating the images dynamically, you can probably find help on SO and/or open a question about it. It's a fairly common task. I am not that familiar with ImageMagick, but you could probably generate all of your images and then serve the correct one in response to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you'll have to create an "image-table", I mean 4 `<td>` elements inside 2 `<TR>` and slice your images in 4 parts. (just if your background colors match for the sticker and all the other images... and so on... so NO.)

I suggest you to do it in your favorite image editor :) just like your Q. example

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `absolute` positioning in emails, as most clients won't render it. What you should do is get an image editor and combine them into a single image.

roXon suggested building an image-table, but that might not be necessary here. I find those particularly handy when you want to have text that is surrounded on two or more sides by a single, large image.

Comment: Of course it's not necessary, it's time consuming and time is money. Professional N-letter creators have their *PhotoShop Boys* that do exactly what I suggested. Use a single image, and make the whole look simple, clear and X-mail-Clients compilant

Comment: @roXon, I don't deny that it's more work :) I was just wondering if there's any gain to splitting the image up in this particular case? Do pardon me if it's some obvious, well-known fact that I'm ignorant of.

Comment: looks like we're both ignorant, take a look at the accepted answer